# Derivation of Hard Thresholding Operator (Least Squares with Pseudo $ {L}_{0} $ Norm)

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, regularization, non-convex-optimization

The problem is given by:

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{f} = \arg \min_{f} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| f - x \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| f \right\|}_{0}.
\end{equation}

How do I find the closed form solution for hard thresholding operator?
I have intuition that $f_i=0$ or $f_i=x_i$ for minimum but can anyone explain the cases and conditions in detail?

Comment: You should note that, despite the "convex-optimization" tag, _this is not convex_. The improper use of the $\|\cdot\|_0$ notation often leads people to believe that it is. But the cardinality function is not a norm, and it is not convex, and writing it that way is an abuse of notation.

Comment: By inspection: $$f_i=\begin{cases} 0 & \tfrac{1}{2}|x_i|_2^2 \leq \lambda \\ x_i & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes I know it is not convex I just tagged to reach out to large community

Comment: You should not do that. Tag for accuracy in categorization.

Comment: Can you please explain the conditions on $x_i$ ? How do we arrive there

Comment: I just noticed that if $f_i\neq 0$, then the best you can do is to set $f_i=x_i$, in which case that component's contribution to the objective is $\lambda$.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4429642.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem can be written as:

$$ \arg \min_{f} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| f - x \right\|}_{2}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| f \right\|}_{0} = \arg \min_{f} \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left( {f}_{i} - {x}_{i} \right)^{2} + \lambda \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ {f}_{i} \neq 0 \right\} } $$

Due to its component wise property one could basically solve the Scalar Problem:

$$ \arg \min_{ {f}_{i} } \frac{1}{2} \left( {f}_{i} - {x}_{i} \right)^{2} + \lambda \mathbb{1}_{ \left\{ {f}_{i} \neq 0 \right\} } $$

Now, in case $ {f}_{i} = 0 $ the cost is $ \frac{1}{2} {x}_{i}^{2} $. Hence as long $ \frac{1}{2} {x}_{i}^{2} \leq \lambda $ it is worth to set $ {f}_{i} = 0 $.
In the other case ($ {f}_{i} \neq 0 $) the minimum value of the cost function is $ \lambda $ where $ {f}_{i} = {x}_{i} $.

Hence:

$$ \tilde{f}_{i} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } \frac{1}{2} {x}_{i}^{2} \leq \lambda \\ 
{x}_{i} & \text{ if } \frac{1}{2} {x}_{i}^{2} > \lambda 
\end{cases} $$

Which is the Hard Threshold operator.